# How can I capture packets in Android?

Tags: android, packet-capture

I would like to capture TCP packets as well as protocol data such as HTTP and HTTPS in Android, similar to Wireshark in Windows.

How can I do this in Android?

Comment: Packet Capture is best option : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Option 1 - Android PCAP

**Limitation**

Android PCAP should work so long as:

Your device runs Android 4.0 or higher (or, in theory, the few devices which run Android 3.2). Earlier versions of Android do not have a USB Host API

### Option 2 - TcpDump

**Limitation**

Phone should be rooted

### Option 3 - bitshark (I would prefer this)

**Limitation**

Phone should be rooted

**Reason -** the generated PCAP files can be analyzed in WireShark which helps us in doing the analysis.

### Other Options without rooting your phone

1. **tPacketCapture**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture&hl=en

**Advantages**

Using tPacketCapture is very easy, captured packet save into a PCAP file that can be easily analyzed by using a network protocol analyzer application such as Wireshark.

2. You can route your android mobile traffic to PC and capture the traffic in the desktop using any network sniffing tool.

http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot

Comment: Thanks a lot and I do not want my device to be rooted :( Any ideas other PCAP ??

Comment: "the generated PCAP files can be analyzed in WireShark which helps us in doing the analysis" - so do the files saved by the other two programs. No need to throw money away on bloatware apps.

Comment: What is bitshark?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth mentioning that for http/https some people proxy their browser traffic through Burp/ZAP or another intercepting "attack proxy".  A thread that covers options for this on Android devices can be found here: 
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32366/which-browser-does-support-proxies