# How to get layer two and layer three messages?

Tags: android, networking

I am trying to acquire layer two L2 and layer three L3 messages-measurements of android. Does anyone now if this is possible through an android application even on a rooted phone? 
Can you suggest any resource with more information on how to read either L2 or L3 data?
Please help.

Comment: I think you can do that with raw sockets. I haven't used them in android but in unix network programs using C. Check UNIX Network Programming
Book by W. Richard Stevens. And look for raw sockets.

Comment: You can record network packets using any options mentioned in the link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887719/how-can-i-capture-packets-in-android